# how to use validator with two variables in one textformfield?

Tags: flutter, dart, validation, user-input

I'd like to ask on if there are anyway on how to compare in a conditional statement the two variable. As you can see, `couponSalePriceCtrlr` and `couponOrigPriceCtrlr`. I'd like to validate that the user's input in `sale price` SHOULD not be greater than the `original price`, but it seems like the `validator` accepts only the `(value)` parameter and a `String` data type.

```
Widget editCouponSalePriceWidget(couponSalePriceCtrlr, couponOrigPriceCtrlr) {
  // converted the variable parameters into double data type
  double convertedSalePrice = double.parse(couponSalePriceCtrlr);
  double convertedOrigPrice = double.parse(couponOrigPriceCtrlr);
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
    child: TextFormField(
      style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Poppins', fontSize: 13),
      controller: couponSalePriceCtrlr,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        suffixText: "*",
        suffixStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
        labelText: 'Sale Price',
        labelStyle: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15, fontFamily: 'Poppins', color: Color(0xFF152C4C)),
        isDense: true,
        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFCECECE)),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFCECECE)),
        ),
        hintText: 'Orig Price',
        fillColor: const Color(0xFFFEFEFE),
        filled: true,
      ),
     // however the validator only accepts, a string data type.
      validator: (convertedSalePrice,convertedOrigPrice) {
        if (convertedSalePrice!.isEmpty ||
            !RegExp(r'[0-9]+[,.]{0,1}[0-9]*').hasMatch(convertedSalePrice)) {
          return "Please enter a valid original price.";
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have 2 `TextFormField`, one for original price, another for sale price. Of course it is `String` type, that's the rule :) Therefore you need to convert it to integer/double type. If your `keyboardType` is number, it is unnecessary to check user's input is string type, else do it.

```
TextFormField(
  controller: couponOrigPriceCtrlr,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
)
```

```
TextFormField(
  controller: convertedSalePrice,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  validator: (saleStr) {
    double originalDouble = double.parse(couponOrigPriceCtrlr.text);
    double saleDouble = double.parse(saleStr.text);
    // check what ever you want here
    // ...

  }
)
```

Comment: `if (saleDouble > originalDouble) { return 'Sale Price should not be greated than original price';} else { return null; }`
I have tried your method, but the validator doesn't check the condition.

Comment: that's strange, i do it overtime, like confirmation password... Remember add condition `if (saleStr == null || saleStr.isEmpty) return;`. Try to add this inside `TextFromField`: `autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode . always `

Comment: thanks, I had to modified some parts of it like, parsing it inside the ``if`` statement directly. anw, your logic worked just had to re-do some of the conditional statement. sorry my bad and thanks!